# d3 mouseover tip.show now working when in function(a, b, c)

Tags: d3.js, tooltip, mouseover

I have d3 tooltip

```
var tip = d3.tip()
.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
.offset([-10, 0])
.html(function(d) {
  return '<strong>Value:</strong> <span class="d3-tip-value>' + d.value + '</span>';
});
svg.call(tip);
```

So I have more code in function(a, b, b) when mouseover dots on the path and also tip.show method which not work by this way:

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(new Date(d.y.date)) })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y.value) })
  .attr("r", 4)
  .on("mouseover", function(a, b, c) {
      tip.show; // NOT WORKING
      ......
```

but tip.show works by this way:

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(new Date(d.y.date)) })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y.value) })
  .attr("r", 4)
  .on("mouseover", tip.show) // WORKING
```

Comment: Try `tip.show(a, b, c)`.

Answer (score -1):

Using: "d3 5.15.0" and "d3-tip 0.9.1"

```
.on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
                tip1.show(d, this), 
                d3.select(this).attr("fill", "red")
            })
.on('mouseout', function(d, i) {
                tip1.hide(d, this), 
                d3.select(this).attr("fill", "black")
            })
```

This works perfectly for me. Passing the "d" and "this" in the show() function and using a normal function and not a new arrow style function seemed todo the trick in order to keep it in the relevant scope.